# How to use active model serialisers only in api namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, serialization

I have a simple rails app which provides CRUD for `User`, `Article`, `Comments` models.

I needed to expose RESTful API to use it from 3rd party services. I added a separate namespace for `/api/v1/....` requests and used [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). But it affected the existing code and all interactions between `UsersController`, `ArticlesController` with views as the serialisation has been changed completely in the whole app.

Is there any way to make serialisers work only with API controllers?

Here are some code:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :email # because I want expose only these attributes in API

  has_many :articles # and show only articles in the API
end
```

The API controller:

```
module Api
  class UsersController < Api::BaseController
    def index
      render json: User.includes(:articles)  # this is API handler and I want only this controller to use the serializers
   end
  end
end
```

But I want the existing `UsersController` to work as I hadn't got any serialisers. The existing controller is a typical controller with view templates and so one.
So the problem is adding serialisers to project (for API controller) broke down the existing controllers which `render json:` in several places.

**Update:**
In routes:

- normal UsersController: `resources :users`
- api UsersController: `namespace :api { resources :users }`

Comment: Could you post some code? Like how you have added AMS in your app and how you've mapped you `UsersController` etc?

Comment: @Surya of course, added some

Comment: The documentation says that rails will look for a serializer first(https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#specify-a-serializer - scroll one line up) : "In this case, Rails will look for a serializer named `PostSerializer`, and if it exists, use it to serialize the Post.". That's why in other controllers `render json:` objects are being serialized with AMS.

Answer (score 0):

All your render :json calls, in any controller within your application, will use the serializers you set up for each model if they have the *default* naming:

```
ArticleSerializer
UserSerializer
```

etc.

But you can specify a *specific* serializer to use within your API controllers, eg.

```
render json: @user, serializer: UserApiSerializer
```

and rename your serializers to match this:

```
UserApiSerializer
```

for example. Then your *default* render :json calls, in non API controllers, should be unaffected by these custom serializers.

However, I think you should consider using [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) for view templates within your API namespace.